# Laravel: can't find random character typo in code that is displayed on even a blanco Blade page

Tags: laravel

I have a typo somewhere in my Laravel project's code that is displaying a 'z' character even when I'm showing a completely empty Blade.

Problem is that I don't know enough of the steps after when a controller picks up a route and returns the view to be processed into Html. Somewhere after this point something sneaks in this typo character.

So if anyone more knowledgeable could help me narrow down the locations to look for?

The Html generated (it's just one line break followed by the character):

```
z
```

The controller calling a completely empty blade.php file

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        return view('testing/empty');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ack, nevermind! I found the problem brute-forcing it, by combing through my commit history >_<

The problem was one files in app\config starting with `z<?php`